# "brought some horses, real heelers.." : what is "heeler" here?

Tags: meaning, poetry, australian-english

I quote from [An Evening in Dandaloo](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/An_Evening_in_Dandaloo)  (1891) by Banjo Paterson:

```
It was while we held our races --
 Hurdles, sprints and steplechases --
 Up in Dandaloo,
 That a crowd of Sydney stealers,
 Jockeys, pugilists and spielers
 Brought some horses, real heelers,
 Came and put us through.
```

I wonder what is the meaning of the word "heeler" here. It seem to refer to "horses".

My initial guess had been "someone who is able to hit it (i.e. run) very fast, striking the road with their heels". But I doubt this sense.

"To heel" may also mean "to follow one closely, keeping at one's heels".

Then I've read that in Australia it [may mean](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heeler) "a cattle dog", possibly a derivation from the previous sense.

I'd like to read your guesses.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_roping ?

Comment: It is a type of dog: [Heeler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heeler)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OED1 (1901) shows the sense “3. One who has light heels; a quick runner”, which fits the context well.

Another sense,  “4. One who catches by the heels; one who trips up, undermines, or supplants” apparently is behind the name of dogs like red or *[blue heelers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_heeler)*, which are called  “’Red Heeler’ or ‘Blue Heeler’ on the basis of this colouring and its practice of moving reluctant cattle by nipping at their heels”.

Comment: Thank you, jwpat7! Is this dictionary online? P.S. Just looked in The Century Dictionary: "1. A cock that strikes well with his heels. 2. A quick runner (Prov. Eng, New Eng.)".

Comment: Yes, although I don't have a link, and what's online is a mediocre scan.  The current OED is online free, I think, in the UK, and via some US libraries or colleges.  I purchased a DVD with OED1 for about $10; also a mediocre scan, but backed by OCR text

Answer (score 1):

This is complete speculation, but given the next verse says these "heelers" *beat our nags and won our money*, it seems at least possible to me the usage is a derivative of...

> [Show a clean pair of heels](http://dictionary.babylon.com/show_a_clean_pair_of_heels/) (Australian slang) *- flee, escape, **run [away] quickly***

Comment: Yes, what else can it be but fast-running horses?

Comment: @FumbleFingers 'Showing a clean pair of heels' is not uniquely Australian. It has been widely used in Britain if slightly dated now.

Comment: @WS2: Off the top of my head I'd have said the same, but while searching for a suitable definition link, I couldn't help noticing that several sites identified it as [originally] Australian slang. And since OP's citation is from AU 120 years ago, it seemed reasonable to stick it in there.